# Ninject Rebind at runtime, can it be used as a feature toggle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

Firstly my question applies only to web apps and I tend to set up the majority of my Ninject bindings with an InRequestScope resolution.

I'm thinking of ways to get feature toggling, and one thought that I have is to call:

```
kernel.Rebind<IInterface>().To<RealImplementation>().InRequestScope();
```

while the website is still up and running, and the switch has been flicked. If I then decide to turn the feature off I could call

```
kernel.Rebind<IInterface>().To<EmptyImplementation>().InRequestScope();
```

My thinking is that the InRequestScope would protect any "in progress" code requests, but will allow new requests to get the newly toggled feature.

Does anyone know from experience (or a deeper understanding of Ninject) if this is likely to work, or if it's going to cause more trouble for me. I've superficially looked at MEF so that'll be my next port of call if Ninject isn't the best tool for the job in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One potential source of issues is that, while the Kernel is thread-safe, you would need to be flicking a single switch or else you're in a race to get everything switched as an atomic action for in-flight requests. (This is in principle, I have not reviewed the code with this question in mind).

Having said that, nothing springs to mind that could directly cause an issue.

But while it may make sense if you can satisfy yourself and/or get a strong enough assurance based on someone who has assessed the code based for race conditions related to this type of use, this is not a widespread practice I've heard off. In fact, the design of AutoFac is such that you Build an immutable Factory from a Configuration input - specifically ruling out this type of thing. My instinct would be to veer away from such an approach for that reason.

Have you considered using `.ToMethod(ctx=> return /* Toggle-based creation*/)` ? (Obviously it doesn't state things as directly as a `Rebind` does). Depending on your real impl (and the complexity of both your bindings and nature of toggle system) this may make sense.

Comment: hmmmm interesting. So if I follow you correctly, your idea is to substitute rebind for .ToMethod wherein the code could validate a condition on a per call basis (e.g. is the flag set). I don't think this would cause any performance overhead since my assumption is that Ninject binds per call rather than caching a return result. In this case I'd be checking azure storage so there would be a check penalty, but this could be cached for x amount of acceptable time.

Comment: @Dylan Less-trivial semantics like that could probably be expressed in a [Provider](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context) (the cache could probably be managed via DI and just be code). Then again, a straightforward static method might fit the bill...